# ping an ls list of domains in bash

Tags: bash, list, for-loop, ping, ls

I am outputting a list of domains like so:

```
lastdomain=`ls -lah /var/www/vhosts | wc -l`
#the variables below will be used later
IP1=`ifconfig | grep "inet addr" | sed '1 ! d' | awk '{print $2;}' | cut -c 6-19`
IP2=`ifconfig | grep "inet addr" | sed '2 ! d' | awk '{print $2;}' | cut -c 6-19`

LIST=`ls -lah /var/www/vhosts | sed "4,$lastdomain ! d" | awk '{print $9;}' | grep -v 'chroot\|default\|.skel'`
```

And I want to ping each one. This almost works:

```
for each in $LIST
 do
 echo "Attempting to ping $each..."
  ping -c 1 $LIST > /dev/null 2>&1 #&& break
   if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "Host $each is not reachable! "
     else
    break
   fi
done
```

However they all return as:

```
Host exampledomain.com is not reachable!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Now that that's working, I need to get rid of the following to just get the IP address:

```
PING domain.com (IP.IP.IP.IP) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from domain.co.uk (IP.IP.IP.IP): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.024 ms

--- domain.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.024/0.024/0.024/0.000 ms
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ping -c 1 $LIST > /dev/null 2>&1
```

You probably meant

```
ping -c 1 $each > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Silly me, that works great, thanks.

Adding note as need some manipulation of the ping result.

Comment: Figured out what I can do:

ping -c 1 $each | sed '1 ! d' | awk '{print $3;}' | cut -c 2-15

Almost there :)

Comment: @Zippyduda sed, awk, AND cut in the same pipeline. That looks terrible, you only need awk there.

Comment: I realise you're on about the ping trimming. Can you suggest what I should use instead? As for ifconfig, it outputs differently on each machine, and it seems difficult to use awk to grab multiple IP addresses. But I get what you're saying.

Doing awk '{print $2;}' results in:

addr:X.X.X.X